# C# Unable to load DLL When In Subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport, unmanaged

I have a third party C# library my code references, let's call it `a.dll`, this library in turn depends on an unmanaged C dll, `cApi.dll`. The C library comes in `x86` and `x64`, and I have them stored in respective folders and `Copy always` set. When I call the init method of `a.dll` from my code I get the error message `Unable to load DLL 'cApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. My code has a reference to `a.dll`, so my bin when debugging looks like:

bin/debug/
---a.dll
      
      ---x86/
      ------cApi.dll
      ---x64/
      ------cApi.dll

When I inspect the code that is in `a.dll` it uses DllImport attribute to make calls to `cApi.dll`. If I copy either of the `cApi.dll`'s to the same directory `a.dll` is output to, I will not get the error. Does DllImport not search the sub directories in the bin? How can I resolve this issue, should I add build logic to copy the correct `cApi.dll` to the same dir as `a.dll`, or is there a way to get it to work with the current structure?

**EDIT** I have a `<probing>` element in my config file: `<probing privatePath="x86;x64"/>`

Comment: No, sub directories are not searched. The DLL search path is used. This is well documented. Best practice is to put all DLLs in the same directory as the executable. If that's not possible then you need to use `SetDllDirectory`.

Comment: James answer below will work however what you're doing isnt the way you are going to release the product. If the customer installs the x64 or x86, put the version you require in the same folder as a.dll and ignore the other.

Comment: Wny would `<probing>` have any impact on unmanaged assemblies?

Comment: @CathalMF, currently that is how this product works for the release version and it works fine. I am new to the project and found that I could not actually debug the specific project locally, so now I have been trying to figure out the correct way to get the project running in debug when run independent of the other projects or an install of the product.